# Use JSON to construct a table using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to make a table which information is stored and updating(not appending) in a JSON file using JavaScript and HTML. The structure of my JSON data is as like as follows:

```
[{
    "A": {
        "name": "MAK",
        "height": 170,
        "place": "Canada"
    },
    "B": {
        "name": "Jak",
        "height": 164,
        "place": "JAPAN"
    },
    "C": {
        "name": "TAKO",
        "height": 152,
        "place": "ROMANIA"
    },
    "D": {
        "name": "NARO",
        "height": 192,
        "place": "Portugal"
    },
    "E": {
        "name": "Monako",
        "height": 138,
        "place": "Poland"
    }
}]
```

**Some details about the provided JSON information:**
1/ With a random interval JSON file will be updated(not append).
2/ Key **A.B.C .....** is not fixed. They could be increased and decreased.
3/Same also for their properties/sub-key(here **name, height, place**). New properties could come or remove.
4/ Besides, I cannot assure that all the time all properties will be present for all key. That means some place could be vacant.
I have added my required [**output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkSak.jpg) which I want to see in the table. Hope it will depict the scenario in a better way. One **flaw** I am seeing here that the (0,0) coordinates of the table is vacant. Should I fill it/ left vacant with any string(probably in any other question it will be solved. If here then obviously awesome)?

**Approach I have taken**
1/ I am new in JavaScript so at first I want to try if I can iterate over the whole object and print all the content. You can see this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8myhponk/7/). It can print all but the formation of the table does not meet the requirements.
2/ I have taken help from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255651/output-json-key-value-in-javascript).

Any solution regarding how to make the table will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. Right now your question reads like you're setting us a task.

Comment: @Mitya I have included the **fiddle** link in the post. For you **again** the [approach](https://jsfiddle.net/8myhponk/7/) I have taken. And the required [output](https://imgur.com/a/vJTe0LM) from  my side.

Answer (score 0):

Here you'll find what you need, do the styling yourself:

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
    var myPersons = [{
        "A": {
            "name": "MAK",
            "height": 170,
            "place": "Canada"
        },
        "B": {
            "name": "Jak",
            "height": 164,
            "place": "JAPAN"
        },
        "C": {
            "name": "TAKO",
            "height": 152,
            "place": "ROMANIA"
        },
        "D": {
            "name": "NARO",
            "height": 192,
            "place": "Portugal"
        },
        "E": {
            "name": "Monako",
            "height": 138,
            "place": "Poland"
        }
    }]
    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    // ('name', 'height', and 'place')
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myPersons.length; i++) {
        for (var key in myPersons[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < myPersons.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myPersons[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I couldn't see any o/p. Maybe I am not understanding the correct path to connect JS and HTML. I have tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gu2e4t63/3/)